# Is it possible to create a connection to a redis server from the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, browserify

Is it possible to create a connection to a redis server from the browser? You can spin up a TCP connection in node using `var client = net.connect(port, host);`. I'm wondering if there is anyway to do this in the browser using Browserify or a native way to connect to the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Not unless it's via HTTP, that's all XHR can perform for you in the browser.

Comment: Can we use socket.io ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly from the browser, but you can make TCP connections with a browser plugin.

Check this url for more info on this: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3972368

Comment: Can we use socket.io ?